# Can't boot arch in EFI mode, rEFInd stuck in installation

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, uefi

I have been trying to install arch on my mid-2011 Macbook air, I moved the ISO to an 8GB USB-Drive with:

```
dd bs=4M if=/home/ronnie/Downloads/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress && sync
```

Then, I restart and get the rEFInd boot-loader and have four choices to boot from the liveUSB. The first one is a tux icon which takes me to:

> rEFInd - Booting OS
>
> Starting vmlinuz-arch.efi
>
> Using load options

and hangs there no matter how long I wait.

The second choice, which says `EFI\bootloader\` and the third one which is a flashback both give me a list and when I chose

> Arch-anywhere x86-64

it goes into a blank screen and nothing happens, I have to press and hold the power button to shut my Mac down.

I tried many other ways, like Architect and Antergos even the official arch ISO from their website and I still get the same problem.

I can boot from Legacy mode though.

How can I install Arch in EFI mode on my mac?